# Getting error of Chatter EntitySubscription limit?

Tags: chatter

I am getting this error on Trigger that creates an EntitySubscription.

Description: Error:Apex trigger trgXYZ caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: first error :CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, trgXYZ: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: LIMIT_EXCEEDED, Maximum per user subscription limit reached.: [] trgXYZ: line 31, column 1[]

Answer (score 2):

You're hitting this because you've hit the maximum number of people, topics, and records you can follow, which is 500. See the "Chatter LImits" section of this document:

https://na10.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf

You may want to consider using the "Chatter Unfollow Rules" app to manage your entity subscriptions:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IX0UEAW

Answer (score 0):

Recently limit has been increased to 700. Which doesn't resolve the error anyway.
It is not documented though.